XCode Previews - Unsupported Frameworks
This may seems like a stupid question, but I have some Pods/Frameworks in an XCode project that doesn't support iOS Simulator (and therefore Previews).
Is there anyway to ignore those frameworks for the preview? 80% of the project doesn't use that framework, but its still pretty key for that 20% and its pretty hampering for development that I cannot access Previews, considering I generally only care about an the individual view (and perhaps the next and previous View).

How about Type-eraser patterns with branch out at compile time?
Let's see this is your framework originally used.
class OriginalFramework {
    func run() {
        /// Don't know its function.
    }
}

Make a protocol for type-erasing abstraction.
protocol AnyFramework {
    // same function signatures originally used.
    func run()
}

And Implement mocking framework class too. This will be executed at preview.
final class MockFramework: AnyFramework {
    func run() {
        print("run")
    }
}

Adopt Eraser protocol to OriginalFramework.
// It must already implements all features of AnyFramework.
extension OriginalFramework: AnyFramework { }

You can detect whether it is started to build by preview or not at compile time. so branch at initializer.
final class FrameworkWrapper: AnyFramework {

    private let framework: AnyFramework

    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    init(framework: MockFramework) {
        self.framework = framework
    }
    #else
    init(framework: OriginalFramework) {
        self.framework = framework
    }
    #endif

    func run() {
        self.framework.run()
    }
}

But you have to rename all places using OriginalFramework(It can be accomplished well with XCode).
struct ViewModel {
    // private var framework: OriginalFramework - not anymore!
    private var framework: FrameworkWrapper

    func tap() {
        self.framework.run()
    }
}

